# missing column header after showing/ hiding column in jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've got a dataTable with the a column declared "hidden" (with { "bVisible":    false, "bSortable": false }) during initialzation.
I need to toogle the visibility of the column with an external button, so I wrote this code:

```
var oSettings = myTable.fnSettings();
oSettings.aoColumns[7].bVisible = !oSettings.aoColumns[7].bVisible;
```

than I a call

```
myTable.fnFilter();
```

to refresh data.

That trick works and the column get hidden or visible but that not happening on the heading of the table. So I get a table with a heading missing.
Someone can help me? Is there a easy way to hide/show a column refreshing also the header?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using Datatables 1.10? It's much much better. The docs are also way better.

Comment: Hi, I've seen the new docs and it is realy much better. In my case I fear some incompatibility of my code with the new version, so I prefer to not update.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved with this code

```
var colsIndex = 7;
myTable.fnSetColumnVis( colsIndex, true );
```

to show the column or

```
var colsIndex = 7;
myTable.fnSetColumnVis( colsIndex, false );
```

to hide it.

thanks anyway